# Simplest (fewest steps) way to measure diameter of a circle in edit mode?

Tags: measurement

Is there a simple (fewer steps) to measure the diameter of a circle in edit mode?

Answer (score 4):

In *Edit Mode* activate *Edge Length* from the *3D View > Overlays* popover.

Extrude a single vertex and see the reported edge length.
Undo once (to avoid an invisble duplicate vertex).

[image]

Comment: Thank you, though my issue if that my circle has 256 vertices, so finding corresponding point pairs is difficult.

Comment: So un-subdivide it, measure it, then undo it. Or create a new circle snap centered on the original one add>mesh>circle and set the radius until it matches.